# How to handle shared resources with pthread mutex

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex, unlock, shared-resource

I have a question regarding mutex and pthreads.

If there is a shared flag, lets call it (F1). And there are multiple threads.
But only one thread (T1) can raise/cease the flag and all other threads (T2..Tn) only reads or pulls the status.

Is it enough if T1 uses mutex_lock/mutex_unlock when the flag F1 will be set with a new value?
Should all other threads also use mutex_lock/mutex_unlock even that they are only going to read the status from F1?

```
Exemple1:

    T1()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            F1 = true;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }

    T2()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            if(F1) {
                /* Do something */
            }
        }
    }



Exemple2:

    T1()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            F1 = true;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }

    T2()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            if(F1) {
                /* Do something */
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the single-writer-multiple-readers idiom.

Reading:

```
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&rwlock);
```

Writing:

```
pthread_rwlock_wdlock(&rwlock);
```

If your use case is as simple as the example you posted, you might consider a lock-free version involving atomic flags.

Answer (score 1):

Under the pthreads model, the readers *do* need to perform a synchronisation operation as well.  This can be a `pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()` pair in both the readers and writer as you've described, or alternatively [metalfox's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39577592/134633) of a reader-writer lock.